# Add attributes to wrapper html generated by wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, walker

I want to add some extra html attributes to the default div html generated by wp_nav_menu. I need to add simple code for example a short style code:
`style="top:10px;"`
*I can't do what I am doing in a css file*; *the html needs to be added in the php*.
I have looked at many examples, of walkers, replacement codes like str_replace. I can't find a solution that functions the way I envision it exactly.
I prefer to not use a walker code that is ten pages long php code just for doing this simple code addition.
If there is not a simple way, the alternative is to wrap the menu in a second div and that is what I will do probably if I can't find another way; but I would prefer to learn a simple way to add the html code to the original div generated by wp_nav_menu.

Comment: If you're surely not interested in modifying the PHP walker script and you can't simply write a CSS declaration that properly targets the element you wish to style, then you have a new definition of "simple" that I am not familiar with.  Assuming you truly have a valid reason why an external CSS solution isn't sufficient, you are left with JS to modify the DOM or adding additional HTML to the source.

Comment: I would need to see the walker to know that. I didn't say I don't want to modify the walker. I just prefer not one that is 10 pages long.

Comment: Most examples I have found are many pages long. Not really what I need.

Comment: I can't use javascript for this. It needs to be php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the wrapper for the `wp_nav_menu()` is customizable with the `items_wrap` parameter.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

The documentation states that the default wrapper is a `<ul>` element with an ID an CLASS attribute.  This can be modified as you wish by modifying the markup passed to the `sprintf()` function used by `wp_nav_menu()`.

The value for `items_wrap` is the argument passed for the wrapper.  To output a `<div>` element with a style attribute:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<div style="css here">%3$s</div>' ) );
```

The `%3$s` in the example represents the items within the wrapper HTML.

Comment: Thanks for following up back in Oct. I ended up using a combination of items_wrap and link_before / link_after to make a 3 part left, center, right, area that allows for very precise alignments. :)